# Regular expression to catch # and a series of numbers

Tags: java, regex

Can someone help me to build a regular expression to catch a `"#"` and a series of numbers in a string?

Example: `"asdadadsa #12345 asdasdasd #67"` in this string I need to replace `#12345` and `#67` with a link like `"com.package.name://#12345"` . I'm working in java but i hope is a general question

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: i try to parse the string char by char but i don't think that it's the better approach

Comment: @ethe: you will get help once you show what you tried and why it didn't work. Post your code (make it short and sweet: http://sscce.org/)

Comment: @ethe: well, it is the faster approach most of the times (if not all of the times). The easier one is to make a regex. Just google regex tutorial and then it's easy.

Answer (score 2):

You need to take a look basic regex, google some tutorial/guide.

back to your question, try this line:

```
String str ="asdadadsa #12345 asdasdasd #67";
String newString = str.replaceAll("#\\d+", "com.package.name://#12345");
```

then the `newString` would be:

```
asdadadsa com.package.name://#12345 asdasdasd com.package.name://#12345
```

**EDIT** based on OP's comment

then you can reference the matched part by `$0, $1, $2...` the `0,1,2` are group index.

So the line turns into:

```
String newString = str.replaceAll("#\\d+", "com.package.name://$0");
```

not the `newString` should have your expected value.

Comment: thanks for this but the content of the replacement should be the result of the search itself. In my example: "asdadadsa #12345 asdasdasd #67" should be "asdadadsa com.package.name://#12345 asdasdasd com.package.name://#67"

Answer (score 0):

I resolved using :

```
message.replaceAll("[#][0-9]+", "<a href=\"$0\">$0</a>");
```

Thanks